# snprintf floating with specified width and specified padded digits and specified precision

Tags: c, c99

I have a float `f = 1.23456`.
I would like to format it in a string to look like:

```
M    01.23
M  01.2345
```

The space depends on variable precision.

My current code is:

```
snprintf(buf, 10, "M%02.*f", precision, f);
```

but the output is not right-justified -> `|M01.234  |`

Is there a way to get what I want?

Comment: Did you try to search for printf ? it will be the same format string than snprintf.

Comment: yup i've and nothign :/ I might have to add the spaces manually

Comment: Thanks, the question is super clear now.

Comment: thanks to Stargateur for formatting it neatly

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to specify the total digits too, via another `*`.  You also need a bigger buffer — a buffer of 10 bytes isn't big enough to hold a string of length 10. Also, the value printed to 4 d.p. will be `1.2346`, not `1.2345`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double f = 1.23456;
    for (int precision = 2; precision < 6; precision += 2)
    {
        char buffer[32];
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%*s%0*.*f", 9 - (precision+3), "", precision+3, precision, f);
        printf("|%s|\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
|M    01.23|
|M  01.2346|
```

The `9 - (precision+3)` is a bit delicate; if precision is more than 6, you don't necessarily get the result you want — or if the value is outside the range [0.0 .. 10.0), etc.  The `+3` (repeated) is also a bit delicate; if the value printed is 10.00 or larger, that needs to change to 4 to get the leading 0 (but do you want `010.2346` or `10.2346`?).  A precision of zero will need special attention too.  What you're asking for is a fiddly format to produce because it isn't a standard one.  What should happen with larger numbers, or larger precisions, or smaller numbers, or negative numbers?  It isn't clear.  This does the requisite job for the two examples for precision and one example value, and shows how variations could be tackled, but it isn't a completely general solution.  You might need to determine `log10(f)` to know what to use in place of the `3`, for example.

#### After clarification in the comments

In summary, the requirements are:

- The values are in the range [0.00 .. 100.00) (including 0.00, excluding 100.00).
- There should be two digits printed before the decimal point, with one or two leading zeros as necessary.
- There should be 1-6 digits printed after the decimal point, depending on the value of precision
- The number should be right justified in a field of 9 characters, with spaces as necessary before the 2 digits before the decimal point
- The number (and any leading spaces) should be preceded by the letter M.

This code demonstrates reasonably comprehensively that the original solution could do the job, but it uses more variables so that it is easier to see what's going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    enum { WIDTH = 9 };
    for (double f = 1.2345678E-7; f < 100.0; f *= 10.0)
    {
        for (int precision = 1; precision <= 6; precision++)
        {
            char buffer[32];
            int f_width = precision + 3;    // decimal point and 2 digits before
            int blanks = WIDTH - f_width;
            snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "M%*s%0*.*f", blanks, "", f_width, precision, f);
            printf("|%s| (b = %d; w = %d; p = %d)\n", buffer, blanks, f_width, precision);
            //printf("|%s|\n", buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.00| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.000| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0000| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.00000| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.000000| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.00| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.000| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0000| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.00000| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.000001| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.00| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.000| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0000| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.00001| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.000012| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.00| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.000| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0001| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.00012| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.000123| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.00| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.001| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0012| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.00123| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.001235| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.0| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.01| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.012| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.0123| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.01235| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.012346| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     00.1| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    00.12| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   00.123| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  00.1235| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 00.12346| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M00.123457| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     01.2| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    01.23| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   01.235| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  01.2346| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 01.23457| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M01.234568| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
|M     12.3| (b = 5; w = 4; p = 1)
|M    12.35| (b = 4; w = 5; p = 2)
|M   12.346| (b = 3; w = 6; p = 3)
|M  12.3457| (b = 2; w = 7; p = 4)
|M 12.34568| (b = 1; w = 8; p = 5)
|M12.345678| (b = 0; w = 9; p = 6)
```

Comment: I was searching with only one conversion specifier, to avoid do it by hand, I think it's not possible to add this 0 and spaces with only one. But yes your solution look OK, However I'm still confuse why OP want this zero.

Comment: I agree the one leading zero is peculiar — there's no explaining taste.  And yes, I don't think it can be done with a single `%…f` specifier because the `0` modifier outputs one or more zeros to width, but the output wants just a single `0`.  However, we've also not been shown how values between 0 and 1 should be presented, nor values 10.00 or larger, nor negative values.  Nor is the range of required precisions stated, …  This is _a_ solution to the two outputs requested — but it is not really a general solution.

Comment: "You might need to determine log10(f) to know what to use in place of the 3, for example."  Can you please elaborate?

Comment: As for "(but do you want 010.2346 or 10.2346?)", I have a limit to 2 digits, no negatives. values between 0 and 1 should still print 00. I agree a special handling for the precision==0 case is needed. Thanks again.

Comment: Not until you elaborate on the range of values you need to print and what these should look like, and the range of precisions you need to support, and what should happen with negative numbers, etc.  Your requirements are woefully under-specified, so it isn't clear whether you need to use `log10(f)` or not.  But you might observe that `3 == (int)log10(f) + 3`.

Comment: You added that values between 0 and 1 should print 00.xyz; what about values between 10 and 100?  You say '2 digits'; presumably, you mean 2 digits before the decimal point, so [0.00 .. 100.00) — using closed-open range notation, not including 100.00.  Should numbers from 10 upwards be printed with a leading 0 or not?  What should the output be for precision 0, or should that be ignored?

Comment: no they shouldn't print a leading 0. Yes the range is [0.00 .. 100.00)

Comment: OK.  So, in summary, the requirements are: • The values are in the range [0.00 .. 100.00) (including 0.00, excluding 100.00) • There should be two digits printed before the decimal point, with one or two leading zeros as necessary • There should be 1-6 digits printed after the decimal point, depending on the value of `precision` • The number should be right justified in a field of 9 characters, with spaces as necessary before the 2 digits before the decimal point • The number (and any leading spaces) should be preceded by the letter `M`.  (Did I miss any requirements?)

Comment: See the updated answer.  The original code meets the requirements outlined in the preceding comment; the revised code makes it easier to see what's going on by using variables instead of expressions (it also avoids repeating expressions for the debug printing).  You don't need to use `log10(f)` for the given required output.

Comment: It does the job. Thanks. I tried to get it in one conversion specifier. But it seems not doable.